# PCA analysis remove centroid

Tags: r, pca, factoextra

I am using `fviz_pca_ind` to make PCA plot see below.

```
 fviz_pca_ind(res.pca,  geom="point",  pointsize = 1, habillage=iris$Species, addEllipses=TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95
             , palette = c("green", "orange", "grey"))
```

I want to remove the centroid but maintain the different colors and ellipses that I get with `habillage=iris$Species`.

`col.ind` requires a vector with a number of elements equal to the lines number.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to remove centroids:

```
library(factoextra)
data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)
fviz(res.pca, element="ind", geom="point",  pointsize = 1, 
              habillage=iris$Species, addEllipses=TRUE, ellipse.level=0.95, 
              palette = c("green", "orange", "grey"), invisible="quali")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is in fact a much simpler way directly in the fviz_pca_ind (and fviz_pca_biplot) function: "To remove the group mean point, specify the argument mean.point = FALSE." ([source](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/)). So:

```
library(factoextra)
data(iris)
res.pca <- prcomp(iris[, -5],  scale = TRUE)
fviz_pca_ind(res.pca,  geom="point",  pointsize = 1, habillage=iris$Species, addEllipses=TRUE,
ellipse.level=0.95, palette = c("green", "orange", "grey"), mean.point=F)
```

Comment: I get an error message `Error in `purrr::pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
ℹ With name: y.
Caused by error in `if (mean.point) ...`:
! the condition has length > 1
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.`