# Why am I getting an extra shape appear on my PCA scores plot?

Tags: r, pca

I am making a script for a PCA scores plot, however I am getting artefacts of an unfilled shape at the centre of each elipse, this appears even if I set my elipse to FALSE. Please can someone help me understand why this is happening and how to get around it.

This is my script;

```
library(factoextra)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)  # for reproducibility
df <- data.frame(
  stage = rep(c("Day 0", "Prebeating", "Beating"), each = 30),
  variable1 = rnorm(90),
  variable2 = rnorm(90),
  variable3 = rnorm(90)
)

colores <- c("red","purple","blue")
  pointss <- c(23,22,21)

pcaData <- df[, -c(1)]
pcaData <- pcaData[, apply(pcaData, 2, var) != 0]
res.pca <-  prcomp(pcaData, center = TRUE, scale. = TRUE)  # Exclude the labels and symbols
labels <- df$stage
fviz_screeplot(res.pca)


fviz_pca_ind(
  res.pca,
  axes = c(1, 2),
  label = "none",
  habillage = labels,
  addEllipses = TRUE,
  ellipse.type = "confidence",
  ellipse.level = 0.95,
  ellipse.alpha = 0.05
) +geom_point(aes(fill=labels, shape=labels), color="black", size=6) +
      scale_shape_manual(values=pointss) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=colores) +
      scale_color_manual(values=colores)
```

This image but without the unfilled shapes: [image: PCA diagram].

Comment: Welcome to SO, Lucy Gill! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a good start, but please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(df))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly randomly), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Try answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46977743/pca-analysis-remove-centroid

Comment: Resolved the issue I was having; this was the solution:

Answer (score 0):

Realised my issue, I was also plotting the centroid was resolved like this. I also added a way to change the axis to note the explained variance

`

```
factoextra::fviz_pca_ind(
  res.pca,
  habillage = factor(labels),
  geom = "point", 
  col.ind = labels,
  palette = colores,
  shape.ind = as.factor(labels),
  addEllipses = TRUE,
  ellipse.type = "confidence",
  ellipse.level = 0.95,
  ellipse.alpha = 0.05,
  pointsize = 2,
  position = position_jitter(2), 
  mean.point=F #get rid of centrdo
) +
labs(title = "PCA Scores Plot",
     x = paste("PC1 (", round(res.pca$sdev[1]^2 / sum(res.pca$sdev^2) * 100, 1), "%)"),
     y = paste("PC2 (", round(res.pca$sdev[2]^2 / sum(res.pca$sdev^2) * 100, 1), "%)"))
```

`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).